Python in Excel: How to install other Anaconda packages
Python in Excel includes some packages in the Anaconda distribution. +info, anaconda distribution packages.
However, is it possible to install additional packages that are still in the Anaconda repository?
For example, let's say we want to install SHAP and LightGBM.

It's not possible for you to install packages when using Microsoft's Python in Excel. The Python code runs in a controlled Azure container and doesn't allow you to install 3rd party packages, or even your own.
You can use any Python packages in Excel using PyXLL (https://www.pyxll.com), however. Disclaimer, I work for PyXLL.
PyXLL is different from Microsoft's Python in Excel in many ways, but one significant difference is that your Python code runs locally without the need for any cloud services, and allows you to use your own Python environment including any packages you want to install.
This FAQ outlines some other significant differences https://support.pyxll.com/hc/en-gb/articles/19792743907987-What-are-the-differences-between-PyXLL-and-Microsoft-s-Python-in-Excel
